# create dataset according to joint/left dates - R

Tags: r, dataset, date-arithmetic

I have the following dataset with information about employees joining and leaving an organisation:

```
dataset1 <- read.table(
  text = "
Employee       Organisation      Joint_date          Left_date
G223           A123              1993-05-15          2019-05-01
G223           A123              2020-04-11          NA
G233           A123              2018-02-20          NA
G234           A123              2015-09-04          NA
G111           A333              1980-10-03          2019-09-27
G122           A333              2000-11-16          NA
G177           A333              2005-01-19          NA
G330           A333              2002-12-24          NA
G556           A333              2018-05-01          2019-03-04
G555           A445              2015-11-18          NA
G556           A445              2005-09-01          2018-03-04
G557           A445              1989-04-05          NA",
  header = TRUE)

dataset1$Employee <- as.factor(dataset1$Employee)
dataset1$Organisation <- as.factor(dataset1$Organisation)
dataset1$Joint_date <- as.Date(dataset1$Joint_date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
dataset1$Left_date <- as.Date(dataset1$Left_date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

I have created dataset2 (monthly dataset) that goes from 2018-01-31 up to 2021-06-30:

```
dataset2_dates=c("2018-01-31","2018-02-28","2018-03-31","2018-04-30","2018-05-31","2018-06-30","2018-07-31","2018-08-31","2018-09-30","2018-10-31","2018-11-30","2018-12-31","2019-01-31","2019-02-28","2019-03-31","2019-04-30","2019-05-31","2019-06-30","2019-07-31","2019-08-31","2019-09-30","2019-10-31","2019-11-30","2019-12-31","2020-01-31","2020-02-29","2020-03-31","2020-04-30","2020-05-31","2020-06-30","2020-07-31","2020-08-31","2020-09-30","2020-10-31","2020-11-30","2020-12-31","2021-01-31","2021-02-28","2021-03-31","2021-04-30","2021-05-31","2021-06-30")

# add dates
dataset2 <- expand.grid(Organisation = unique(dataset1$Organisation),
                       Month = dataset2_dates)
  
## sort
dataset2 <- dataset2[order(dataset2$Organisation, dataset2$Month),]
## reset id
rownames(dataset2) <- NULL

dataset2$Organisation <- as.factor(dataset2$Organisation)
dataset2$Month <- as.Date(dataset2$Month, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

I would like to end up with the following `dataset3`:

```
Organisation    | Month         | Nr_employees      
A123            | 2018-01-31    | 2
A123            | 2018-02-28    | 3
A123            | 2018-03-31    | 3
A123            | 2018-04-30    | 3
A123            | 2018-05-31    | 3
A123            | 2018-06-30    | 3
A123            | 2018-07-31    | 3
A123            | 2018-08-31    | 3
A123            | 2018-09-30    | 3
A123            | 2018-10-31    | 3
A123            | 2018-11-30    | 3
A123            | 2018-12-31    | 3
A123            | 2019-01-31    | 3
A123            | 2019-02-28    | 3
A123            | 2019-03-31    | 3
A123            | 2019-04-30    | 3
A123            | 2019-05-31    | 3
A123            | 2019-06-30    | 2
A123            | 2019-07-31    | 2
A123            | 2019-08-31    | 2
A123            | 2019-09-30    | 2
A123            | 2019-10-31    | 2
A123            | 2019-11-30    | 2
A123            | 2019-12-31    | 2
A123            | 2020-01-31    | 2
A123            | 2020-02-29    | 2
A123            | 2020-03-31    | 2
A123            | 2020-04-30    | 3
A123            | 2020-05-31    | 3
A123            | 2020-06-30    | 3
A123            | 2020-07-31    | 3
A123            | 2020-08-31    | 3
A123            | 2020-09-30    | 3
A123            | 2020-10-31    | 3
A123            | 2020-11-30    | 3
A123            | 2020-12-31    | 3
A123            | 2021-01-31    | 3
A123            | 2021-02-28    | 3
A123            | 2021-03-31    | 3
A123            | 2021-04-30    | 3
A123            | 2021-05-31    | 3
A123            | 2021-06-30    | 3
.....
```

Note: If an employee joins on the last day of the month or leaves on the first day of the month, it still counts as if the employee was there the whole month.

And `dataset4` that summarises data from 2018-01-31 to 2021-06-30:

```
Organisation  | Average Nr_employees  | Nr_employees joined | Nr_employess left | Nr_employess stayed the whole time
A123          | 115/42 = 2.7          | 2                   | 1                 | 1
....
```

Any ideas on how to generate `dataset3` and `dataset4`?

Comment: it is not clear what month in dataset 3 represents?

Comment: what do you want to do with the case when joint and left date is different? which jmonth it should be assigned? what do you want to do with cases where either joint or left date is NA? what to do with cases where join day is earlier than what you have in dataset 2?

Comment: Thanks @yuliaUU for looking into this. Please see below: 1-"Month" is just a given month of my dataset that goes from Jan 2018 to Jun 2021. 2-Joint and left date are usually different but it can happen for them to be the same. E.g. employee join in Jan 2021 and leave Jan 2021, in that case dataset3 shows current Nr_employee +1 for Jan 2021 and then we subtract 1 employee for Feb 2021. 3-There are no cases where either joint date is NA, only left data can be NA.

Comment: 4-When joint date is earlier than dataset2 (2018-01-31) e.g. for 1 organisation there is only 1 employee with joint date: 2000-01-01 & left date: NA, then in dataset3 for 2018-01-31 Nr_employees = 1, for 2018-02-28 Nr_employees = 1, etc. & dataset4 should say Average Nr_employees = 1, Nr_employees joined = 0, Nr_employess left = 0, Nr_employess stayed the whole time (which is between Jan 2018 and Jun 2021) = 1.

Comment: In dataset 4, do you want the avg nr_employees to be specific to an organisation, but the other stats across all organisations? I think that's what the desired output suggests.

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring. Sorry if confusing. I would like all metrics specific to the organisation across time (2018-2021).

Comment: Hi @JonSpring, do you have any ideas about how to go about creating dataset4?

Comment: I have started a bounty for this question - anyone has any ideas for dataset4? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to work with the `data.table` package - for problems like creating `dataset3`, the non-equijoin functionality is a great fit.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataset1)    

dataset2 <- CJ(Organisation = dataset1[,unique(Organisation)],
               ## This is an option to generate the month sequence based on the first date in dataset1 to present
               # Month = seq.Date(from = as.Date(cut.Date(dataset1[,min(Joint_date)], breaks = "months")),
               #                  to = as.Date(cut.Date(Sys.Date(), breaks = "months")),
               #                  by = "month") - 1
               ## Otherwise you can still generate a full sequence of month-end dates with just a start and end
               Month = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2018-02-01"),
                                to = as.Date("2021-07-01"),
                                by = "month") - 1)

## Simpler to compare month start dates than end
dataset2[,MonthStart := as.Date(cut.Date(Month, breaks = "months"))]

## Fill NA's for Left_date with today's date to properly account for employees still present
dataset1[,Left_date_fill := data.table::fcoalesce(Left_date, Sys.Date())]

## Create columnns with the month start dates of arrivals/departures
dataset1[,Joint_date_month := as.Date(cut.Date(Joint_date, breaks = "months"))]
dataset1[,Left_date_fill_month := as.Date(cut.Date(Left_date_fill, breaks = "months"))]

## Use a non-equijoin to summarize the number of employees present by month
dataset2[dataset1, Nr_employees := .N, by = .(Organisation,
                                              Month), on = .(Organisation = Organisation,
                                                             MonthStart >= Joint_date_month,
                                                             MonthStart <= Left_date_fill_month)]

## Using this method, the information required for `dataset3` has been added to `dataset2` instead
print(dataset2[seq_len(5), .(Organisation, Month, Nr_employees)])
#    Organisation      Month Nr_employees
# 1:         A123 2018-01-31            2
# 2:         A123 2018-02-28            3
# 3:         A123 2018-03-31            3
# 4:         A123 2018-04-30            3
# 5:         A123 2018-05-31            3
# 6:         A123 2018-06-30            3
```

To create a summary table like `dataset4`, it makes the most sense to me to break up each of the steps into a separate operation:

```
## Start with a table of organizations for dataset4
dataset4 <- data.table(Organisation = dataset1[,unique(Organisation)])

## Join on a summary of dataset2 to get the average over the window of interest
dataset4[dataset2[,.(Avg = mean(fcoalesce(Nr_employees),0.0)), by = .(Organisation)]
         ,Average_Nr_employees := Avg, on = .(Organisation)]

## Join a summary of dataset1 counting the number that joined in the window of interest
dataset4[dataset1[Joint_date_month >= dataset2[,min(MonthStart)]
                  & Joint_date_month <= dataset2[,max(MonthStart)]
                  , .(N = .N)
                  , by = .(Organisation)], Nr_employees_joined := N, on = .(Organisation)]

## Join a summary of dataset1 counting the number that left in the window of interest
dataset4[dataset1[Left_date_fill_month >= dataset2[,min(MonthStart)]
                  & Left_date_fill_month <= dataset2[,max(MonthStart)]
                  , .(N = .N)
                  , by = .(Organisation)], Nr_employees_left := N, on = .(Organisation)]

## Join a summary of dataset1 counting the number that joined before and left after window of interest
dataset4[dataset1[Joint_date_month <= dataset2[,min(MonthStart)]
                  & Left_date_fill_month >= dataset2[,max(MonthStart)]
                  , .(N = .N)
                  , by = .(Organisation)], Nr_employees_stayed := N, on = .(Organisation)]

print(dataset4)
#    Organisation Average_Nr_employees Nr_employees_joined Nr_employees_left Nr_employees_stayed
# 1:         A123             2.738095                   2                 1                   1
# 2:         A333             3.761905                   1                 2                   3
# 3:         A445             2.071429                  NA                 1                   2
```

Comment: Thanks very much Matt. It seems to be working perfectly in the testing data and I am now running it on my real data. I just have a question, how to change Sys.Date() below to "2021-06-30"? I tried to just type that but got an error. I worry that the current number of employees is not appropriate because I only care until 2021-06-30, some might have left / joined after that, but it is not relevant. How to change this please?

## Fill NA's for Left_date with today's date to properly account for employees still present
dataset1[,Left_date_fill := data.table::fcoalesce(Left_date, Sys.Date())]

Comment: Instead of Sys.Date() you can set your max_date, i.e. as.Date("2021-06-30"). Alternatively, you can filter the data frame for your liked max_date.

Comment: Thanks Ray. I think it works this way. I ended up choosing as.Date("2021-07-01") in there, otherwise calculations for dataset4 were not correct, but Matt can you please confirm this? Thanks!

Comment: If your range of analysis ends at 2021-06-30, then filling `NA` values in `Left_date` with any date after that 2021-06-30 _(i.e. `as.Date("2021-07-01")` or `Sys.Date()` )_ should give the same results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. I have accepted your answer, it works perfectly. Can I ask one last question - is it easy to create a dataset 5 where we have the same info as presented in dataset 4, but for periods of 6 months : Jan-Jun 2018; Jul-Dec 18; Jan-Jun 2019; Jul-Dec 19; Jan-Jun 2021? So every organisation repeated 5x in the dataset, according to these time periods. I can post another question, if that's not an easy tweak to the code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this works. My approach was to reshape the data into longer format, then count each Joint_date line as adding +1 employee, and otherwise we're looking at a departure and -1.

The middle bit converts each date to end of the month, and in the case of a departure to the end of the following month (since you note that we want someone who left in the month to still count in that month; they don't decrement the total until the next month).

The `complete(Organisation, ...` step adds in blank rows for the months in the period of interest which might have had no change.

Finally, we count how many net additions and departures per month, per organization, with the employee count being the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) of those changes.

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)

# convenience function to return the last day of the month
eom <- function(date) { ceiling_date(date, "month") - 1}

dataset1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Employee:Organisation)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(change = if_else(name == "Joint_date", 1, -1),
         date = value %>% ymd %>% eom,
         Month = if_else(change == -1, eom(date + 10), date)) %>%

  complete(Organisation, 
           Month = ceiling_date(seq.Date(ymd(20180101), ymd(20210601), "month"),"month")-1,
           fill = list(change = 0)) %>% 
  count(Organisation, Month, wt = change, name = "change") %>%
  
  group_by(Organisation) %>%
  mutate(Nr_employees = cumsum(change)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon, I am checking your code against my real dataset but so far it seems it works perfectly. Do you have any ideas for dataset4? Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Here is an other `data.table`, but with a different approach than the answer by Matt.

Code explanation is inside the comments

```
library(data.table)
# Set dataset1 to data.table format
setDT(dataset1)
# Faster way to create dataset 2
dataset2_dates <- seq(as.Date("2018-02-01"), as.Date("2021-07-01"), by = "1 months") - 1
dataset2 <- CJ(Organisation = dataset1$Organisation, 
               Month = dataset2_dates,
               unique = TRUE, sorted = TRUE)
# Create dataset3 using a series of two non-equi joins
dataset2[, Nr_employees := 0]
# First non-equi for people that already left (so month should be between joint-left)
dataset2[dataset1[!is.na(Left_date)], 
         Nr_employees := Nr_employees + .N, 
         by = .(Organisation, Month), 
         on = .(Organisation = Organisation, Month >= Joint_date, Month <= Left_date)]
# Second non-equi for people are still around (so month should be after joint)
dataset2[dataset1[is.na(Left_date)], 
         Nr_employees := Nr_employees + .N, 
         by = .(Organisation, Month), 
         on = .(Organisation = Organisation, Month >= Joint_date)]
#      Organisation      Month Nr_employees
#   1:         A123 2018-01-31            2
#   2:         A123 2018-02-28            3
#   3:         A123 2018-03-31            3
#   4:         A123 2018-04-30            3
#   5:         A123 2018-05-31            3
# ---                                     
# 122:         A445 2021-02-28            2
# 123:         A445 2021-03-31            2
# 124:         A445 2021-04-30            2
# 125:         A445 2021-05-31            2
# 126:         A445 2021-06-30            2

# Initialise dataset4
dataset4 <- dataset2[, .(Average_Nr_employees = mean(Nr_employees)), by = .(Organisation)]
#    Organisation Average_Nr_employees
# 1:         A123             2.714286
# 2:         A333             3.714286
# 3:         A445             2.047619

#set boundaries to summarise on
minDate <- min(dataset2$Month, na.rm = TRUE)
maxDate <- max(dataset2$Month, na.rm = TRUE)

# Now, get relevant rows from dataset1
dataset4[ dataset1[ is.na(Left_date) | Left_date >= minDate, 
                    .(Nr_employees_joined = uniqueN(Employee[Joint_date >= minDate]),
                      Nr_employees_left   = uniqueN(Employee[!is.na(Left_date) & Left_date <= maxDate]),
                      Nr_employees_stayed = uniqueN(Employee[Joint_date <= minDate & (is.na(Left_date) | Left_date >= maxDate)])
                      ), by = .(Organisation)],
          on = .(Organisation)][]
#    Organisation Average_Nr_employees Nr_employees_joined Nr_employees_left Nr_employees_stayed
# 1:         A123             2.714286                   2                 1                   1
# 2:         A333             3.714286                   1                 2                   3
# 3:         A445             2.047619                   0                 1                   2
```

Comment: Thanks Wimpel. Something weird is happening with dataset4. I see only "3 obs. of 2 variables" -including 'Organisation' and 'Average_Nr_employees'. But in my console it generated the below. Any ideas?
Organisation Average_Nr_employees Nr_employees_joined
1:         A123             2.714286                   2
2:         A333             3.714286                   1
3:         A445             2.047619                   0
   Nr_employees_left Nr_employees_stayed
1:                 1                   1
2:                 2                   3
3:                 1                   2

Comment: strange.. did you run all of the code in the answer on your own sample data?

Comment: yes, I also see this weird behaviour with real data. I think it might have to do with "data table", I have seen this happening before, and it happened once with Matt's code, but last time it worked fine. It is very strange. Matt was the first to enter an answer to this question so I will have to give him the points, but form my checks I think your solution also works. It was just the number of variables that was unexpected.